# directive scope variables not accessible in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I have a directive like below:

```
angular.module('buttonModule', []).directive('saveButton', [
function () {

    function resetButton(element) {
        element.removeClass('btn-primary');
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'false',
        scope: {
            isSave: '='
        },
        template:
            '<button class="btn" href="#" style="margin-right:10px;" ng-disabled="!isSave">' +

            '</button>',
        link: function (scope, element) {               
            console.log(scope.isSave);
            scope.$watch('isSave', function () {
                if (scope.isSave) {
                    resetButton(scope, element);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
]);
```

and the jasmine test as below:

```
describe('Directives: saveButton', function() {

var scope, compile;

beforeEach(module('buttonModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
}));

function createDirective() {
    var elem, compiledElem;
    elem = angular.element('<save-button></save-button>');
    compiledElem = compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    return compiledElem;    
}

it('should set button clean', function() {

    var el = createDirective();
    el.scope().isSaving = true;
    expect(el.hasClass('btn-primary')).toBeFalsy();     
});

});
```

The issue is the value of isSaving is not getting reflected in the directive and hence resetButton function is never called. How do i access the directive scope in my spec and change the variable values. i tried with isolateScope but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*First note that you are calling the `resetButton` function with two arguments when it only accepts one. I fixed this in my example code. I also added the class `btn-primary` to the button element to make the passing of the test clearer.*

Your directive is setting up two-way databinding between the outer scope and the isolated scope:

```
scope: {
  isDirty: '=',
  isSaving: '='
}
```

You should leverage this to modify the `isSaving` variable.

Add the `is-saving` attribute to your element:

```
elem = '<save-button is-saving="isSaving"></save-button>';
```

Then modify the `isSaving` property of the scope that was used when compiling (you also need to trigger the digest loop to make the watcher detect the change):

```
var el = createDirective();

scope.isSaving = true;
scope.$apply();

expect(el.hasClass('btn-primary')).toBeFalsy();
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Fr08guUMIxTLYTY0wTW3?p=preview

If you don't want to add the `is-saving` attribute to your element and still want to modify the variable you need to retrieve the isolated scope:

```
var el = createDirective();

var isolatedScope = el.isolateScope();
isolatedScope.isSaving = true;
isolatedScope.$apply();

expect(el.hasClass('btn-primary')).toBeFalsy();
```

For this to work however you need to remove the two-way binding to `isSaving`:

```
scope: {
  isDirty: '='
}
```

Otherwise it would try to bind to something non-existing as there is no `is-saving` attribute on the element and you would get the following error:

> Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'saveButton' is
>   non-assignable!
>   (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=saveButton)

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Ud6nK2qYxzQMi6fXNw1t?p=preview

Comment: I was getting this same error and I just solved it by making sure optional parameters had `'=?'` in the directive scope definition.